# Confusion about Galen Strawson's Basic argument

Tags: free-will

According to Galen Strawson's "The Impossibility of Moral Responsibility", unless I'm interpreting it incorrectly, I believe he's saying you can't have free will and be responsible unless you're responsible for your nature. Is this because the way you are isn't up to you or because if the way you are isn't up to you, then the actions you make aren't up to you either? Or is he saying you cannot be responsible for the way you are unless you're responsible for the actions you take?

Comment: According to GS, you are not responsible for your nature, because that is down to genetics, your upbringing, your environment, etc. And if you are not responsible for your nature, you are not responsible for your actions either, since these are at least partially determined by your nature. It is a highly contentious claim, and in effect amounts to an attempt to redefine the concept of responsibility.

Comment: Would it be wrong to interpret his text as saying that it is possible to be responsible for your nature *if* you are really responsible for choosing to act in a certain way?

Comment: To say, if you responsible for choosing to act then you are responsible for your nature, is the contrapositive of what GS says. So it is a true reading, but sounds misleading because his claim is that you are in fact responsible for neither.

Comment: Yes, so the argument has 2 basic parts. One is "You are not ultimately responsible for your own nature." and the second is the implication, "If you are not ultimately responsible for your nature, then you are not ultimately responsible for your actions." Both combined imply you are not ultimately responsible for your actions.

Comment: @moh abdi "I believe he's saying..." hmm, maybe try to find a reliable quote. Usually that should solve your question. try plato.stanford